# How can I leave just one site?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

I have accounts on several Stack Exchange sites. I do not wish to be removed from all of them, just one or two that I never really use and am no longer interested in. Is this possible? If so, how? If not, please consider this a feature request.

Comment: Like many others, I suspect, I have signed up for one or two SE sites that I don't really partake in. While there is no harm in remaining, it makes sense that I leave them... but like you, I see no way of doing this. It's curious that at least 8 others agree, yet no-one else has answered or commented.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can delete your own account in two ways:

1. If your profile has little or no activity, go to the profile, click "Edit Profile & Settings", and then use the "Delete Profile" link on the left:

> [image]

2. If you have been participating on the site for a while, go to the contact page ("contact us" at the bottom of any page on the site) and choose "I need to delete my user profile" from the dropdown.

All profile deletions are per-site, so you can leave an individual community without affecting the others. If you are on a lot of Stack Exchange sites and want to leave them all at once, the most expedient way to do so is to email the team and request network-wide deletion by going to the "contact us" page, choosing "Other" from the list of topics, and explaining your request/situation.

Comment: Before I try this, can anyone official confirm that this will work?

Comment: @ericgorr It will work, but you can only delete your own site profiles where you haven't had much activity. To delete profiles with posts on them, you have to contact us via the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page. See here for more info: [How can I delete my account?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-deletion, @ericgorr

Comment: @AnnaLear Are the vote/comment associations kept when the account is deleted in this way? So, if one decides to join again, can (s)he view his/her comments at the activity tab?

Comment: @RobW No, if the account is removed and the user later signs up again, none of the questions, answers, votes, or any other activity are mapped back.

Comment: the link doesn't work

Comment: This link doesn't work for me either. Perhaps it was changed? Also, this may not be useful for some, but one can go to the "Edit Profile" section of their account then the "Communities" tab and hide certain communities.

Comment: Looks like it's been changed - I've updated the question to reflect the site's new layout. However the functionality seems to be broken. Following my  instructions removes the community of your list of communities but doesn't actually remove you from the community.

Comment: @munyengm I updated your answer with the current ways to get your profile deleted. The site switcher only tracks the sites you're interested in tracking (top 5 by rep by default, but you can customize it - and even add sites you don't have profiles on). :) Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Is this information still up-to-date as of Januar 2017 ?

Comment: @Criggie it "doesn't work" most likely because you have some activity, hence don't get the instant profile deletion.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd point.  Making it hard to leave a stack means that betas seem to have more support than they really do.  In my case parenting.se is in beta, and I specifically wanted to remote my support for that site as it stands.  Not straight forward, obviously.

Comment: Instead of leaving you could also just opt to hide the affected communities. That way, it won't be shown to you or people viewing your profile page without cutting ties to answers and comments you might have already made.

Comment: I just followed the process to successfully leave a single stack-site. No real issues, other than my own unfounded concern that I might accidentally be removing all sites. Seems to have worked just fine.

Comment: not there anymore, how is this useful to the community?

Answer (score 0):

**StackOverflow** and **StackExchange** are different subdomains behind the scene, it sounds contradictory, but that's the process to 'sign in' and 'sign out' individually for each community.

To solve it, you can use this simple way:

If you want to 'Delete account' (you need to wait 24hrs to complete deleted), but you can still...

1. **Log out** just in the specific community only.
2. **Log in** with the correct 'user' account if you need.

[image]

To check all your communities in StackOverFlow main domain
https://stackoverflow.com/

To check each account linked and communities individually
https://meta.stackexchange.com/