# Delete site account functionality broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, linked-accounts

It looks like deleting a site from one's profile no longer works.

I've updated [an answer I provided previously](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80864/how-can-i-leave-just-one-site/) to reflect the latest site layout however, as per my comment (at bottom of the question) the functionality seems to be broken.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting a site from the "Your Communities" section of the site switcher has nothing to do with deleting user profiles. :)

That section exists to allow people to have a way to access their frequently used sites or just sites they're curious about faster.

I updated your answer on the other post with current screenshots/instructions. Sorry about the confusion here.